# Reverse-engineering EVI Daily product (MODIS_MOD09GA_006_EVI) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Up until recently, Google's been generating an EVI daily product based off MOD09GA. When the MODIS data switched from 006 to 061, this product ceased being updated. I assume this dataset was based on calculations from (roughly) daily observations.

I'm hoping anyone familiar with this can guide me either to (1) the team responsible for this daily EVI product so I can ask them some questions or (2) a way to reverse-engineer this product. I assume there's some averaging, cloud correction, etc.